# Classic ASP, Send POST Request do other domain

Tags: post, asp-classic

I want to be able to send a simple post from an ASP code.

The examples shown in an API tutorial show the use of simple HTML, like that:

```
<form action="http://api_domain/name_of_function" method="post">
    <input name="field1" type="Text"/>
    <input name="field2" type="Text"/>
</form>
```

So this HTML sends a post to the API. The POST is sent from the user, from the browser. It may be OK, but the API requires authentication, and placing username and password info inside a form which is sent to the customer is, of course, unacceptable.

Are there any ways to do it from the server, using classic ASP? (I need to send not just textual fields, but also files which I form in the ASP code)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to do this using the MSMXL object.
var server = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.3.0");

You can see more details and the documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms766431%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Before asking if non-xml data can be transmitted that way, I would appreciate if there would be an example of how to send an actual file through post, like there was a field `<input type="file"` in the form.

Comment: You can send any type of data is just a POST request similar to using curl in linux.

See this longer example (it's sending xml but as a binary file)

http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.xml.msxml-webrelease/browse_thread/thread/ad58807d9443d49e?pli=1